# Different functional equations than Cauchy type? $2f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Since we have solution for Cauchy functional equation,
$$f(xy)= f(x)+f(y)$$
which is $C\log(x)$. However, if we have
$$2f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$$
type of functional equation, I found that its solutions are any arbitrary constant $C$, but failed to prove.

How do I prove the above claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $y = 1$ we obtain $f(x) = f(1)$ so $f$ is constant.

Comment: Why do you choose only y=1 and why not y any real  number? If we let x= y then we have f(x^2)= f(x) still the solution is same but how is constant function I'm not getting ?

Comment: @LeeLee1729 The $f(xy)$ term looks complicated. So let's substitute something so that it isn't complicated anymore. For example, $y = 1$.